# Not able to start virtual machine/domain in KVM: Failed to get "write" lock

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

After host's restart, I'm not able to start virtual machine:

```
user@server-1:~$ virsh start docker-1
error: Failed to start domain docker-1
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2021-03-23T01:21:58.149079Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-2-storage","backing":null}: Failed to get "write" lock
Is another process using the image [/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2]?
```

File is not in use:

```
user@server-1:~$ sudo fuser -u /apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2
user@server-1:~$ sudo lsof | grep qcow
user@server-1:~$ virsh list
 Id   Name   State
--------------------

user@server-1:~$
```

I have tried on Ubuntu 18.04/qemu 2.11 and upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04/qemu 4.2.1

This upgrade didn't help to solve an issue.

This VM is very big so can't easily create new one from it, there is no available space.

Any help to recover from this situation and start this domain?

Thank you

---

UPDATE

attaching output of locks:

```
user@server-1:~$ sudo lslocks -u
COMMAND           PID  TYPE SIZE MODE  M      START        END PATH
blkmapd           583 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/blkmapd.pid
rpcbind          1181 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run/rpcbind.lock
lxcfs            1312 POSIX   5B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/lxcfs.pid
atd              1456 POSIX   5B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/atd.pid
whoopsie         1454 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run/lock/whoopsie/lock
virtlogd         6143 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/virtlogd.pid
multipathd       1106 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/multipathd.pid
containerd       1401 FLOCK 128K WRITE 0          0          0 /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt/meta.db
tracker-miner-f  1561 POSIX 3.6M READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 /var/lib/gdm3/.cache/tracker/meta.db
tracker-miner-f  1561 POSIX  32K READ  0        128        128 /var/lib/gdm3/.cache/tracker/meta.db-shm
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/network/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/interface/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/secrets/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/storage/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/nodedev/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/nwfilter/driver.pid
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirt/qemu/driver.pid
tracker-miner-f  8956 POSIX 3.6M READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 /home/user/.cache/tracker/meta.db
tracker-miner-f  8956 POSIX  32K READ  0        128        128 /home/user/.cache/tracker/meta.db-shm
dmeventd          581 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/dmeventd.pid
cron             1445 FLOCK   5B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/crond.pid
gnome-shell      1713 FLOCK      WRITE 0          0          0 /run/user/126/wayland-0.lock
libvirtd         6057 POSIX   4B WRITE 0          0          0 /run/libvirtd.pid
```

and attaching process table:

```
user@server-1:~$ ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 01:11 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
root           2       0  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root           3       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root           4       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root           6       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H-kblockd]
root           9       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root          10       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root          11       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 [rcu_sched]
root          12       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root          13       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/0]
root          14       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/0]
root          15       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/1]
root          16       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/1]
root          17       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root          18       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root          20       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H-kblockd]
root          21       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/2]
root          22       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/2]
root          23       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root          24       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root          26       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H-kblockd]
root          27       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/3]
root          28       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/3]
root          29       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root          30       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root          32       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H-events_highpri]
root          33       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root          34       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root          35       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_tasks_kthre]
root          36       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root          38       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root          39       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [oom_reaper]
root          40       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root          41       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kcompactd0]
root          42       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root          43       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
root          89       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root          90       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root          91       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [blkcg_punt_bio]
root          93       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [tpm_dev_wq]
root          94       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root          95       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root          96       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [edac-poller]
root          97       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
root          98       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [watchdogd]
root         101       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root         102       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root         104       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root         105       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [irq/122-aerdrv]
root         106       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root         107       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [vfio-irqfd-clea]
root         111       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root         120       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kstrp]
root         123       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u9:0-xprtiod]
root         138       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
root         197       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [cryptd]
root         224       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root         225       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root         226       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root         227       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root         228       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root         229       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root         230       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root         231       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_3]
root         232       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_4]
root         233       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_4]
root         234       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root         235       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_5]
root         241       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root         245       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_6]
root         246       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_6]
root         247       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:02 [usb-storage]
root         248       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_7]
root         249       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_7]
root         250       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [usb-storage]
root         251       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1H-kblockd]
root         252       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [uas]
root         253       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1H-kblockd]
root         254       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H-kblockd]
root         286       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [raid5wq]
root         287       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         288       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         290       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         292       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         297       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         319       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [mdX_raid1]
root         326       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         327       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         328       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         330       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         331       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kdmflush]
root         363       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [mdX_raid1]
root         476       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sda2-8]
root         477       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root         552       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod]
root         553       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [xprtiod]
root         554       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root         581       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/dmeventd -f
root         583       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/blkmapd
root         597       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root         635       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [irq/133-mei_me]
root         697       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [led_workqueue]
root        1102       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kaluad]
root        1103       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kmpath_rdacd]
root        1104       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kmpathd]
root        1105       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kmpath_handlerd]
root        1106       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:04 /sbin/multipathd -d -s
root        1115       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/dm-4-8]
root        1117       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root        1120       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop0]
root        1126       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop1]
root        1129       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop2]
root        1131       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/dm-9-8]
root        1132       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root        1135       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop3]
root        1137       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop4]
root        1138       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [loop5]
root        1145       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/sde1-8]
root        1146       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
systemd+    1176       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
root        1177       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
_rpc        1181       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rpcbind -f -w
systemd+    1182       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
systemd+    1187       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
root        1296       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root        1297       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
avahi       1301       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [server-1.local]
root        1302       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
message+    1303       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
root        1304       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
root        1310       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --foreground
root        1312       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs
root        1314       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root        1322       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
syslog      1329       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
root        1335       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -n
root        1340       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/switcheroo-control
root        1341       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root        1342       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-machined
root        1343       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:09 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
root        1344       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
avahi       1353    1301  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root        1383       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
root        1386       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
root        1401       1  0 01:11 ?        00:02:22 /usr/bin/containerd
root        1416       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rpc.mountd --manage-gids
root        1445       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
whoopsie    1454       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/whoopsie -f
daemon      1456       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
root        1457       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u9:1-xprtiod]
root        1458       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups
root        1460       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [lockd]
kernoops    1463       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/kerneloops --test
kernoops    1474       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/kerneloops
root        1477       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
root        1486       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
root        1496    1486  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
gdm         1527       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
gdm         1528    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
root        1552       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 bpfilter_umh
gdm         1559    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
gdm         1561    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
gdm         1568    1496  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session dbus-run-session -- gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm         1577    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
gdm         1584    1568  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 dbus-run-session -- gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm         1585    1584  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 dbus-daemon --nofork --print-address 4 --session
rtkit       1586       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/rtkit-daemon
gdm         1589    1584  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm         1590    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
gdm         1600    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/126/gvfs -f -o big_writes
gdm         1608    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
gdm         1640    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
gdm         1648    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
gdm         1653    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
gdm         1686       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
gdm         1702    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
gdm         1711    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:01 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
gdm         1713    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:13 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
gdm         1723    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
root        1729       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/upower/upowerd
root        1800       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1801       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1802       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1803       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1804       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1805       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1806       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
root        1807       2  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 [nfsd]
gdm         1868       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
gdm         1874    1868  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
gdm         1880    1713  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -noreset -accessx -core -auth /run/user/126/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.XH3U00 -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6 -listen 7
libvirt+    1916       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
root        1917    1916  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf --leasefile-ro --dhcp-script=/usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt_leaseshelper
gdm         2003       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/xdg-permission-store
gdm         2052       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Notifications
gdm         2054       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
gdm         2066    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-sharing
gdm         2069    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-wacom
gdm         2070    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-color
gdm         2075    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-keyboard
gdm         2078    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-print-notifications
gdm         2079    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-rfkill
gdm         2084    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-smartcard
gdm         2090    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-datetime
gdm         2103    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-media-keys
gdm         2110    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-screensaver-proxy
gdm         2111    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-sound
gdm         2112    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-a11y-settings
gdm         2114    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:03 /usr/libexec/gsd-housekeeping
gdm         2116    1589  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-power
gdm         2179    1713  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 ibus-daemon --panel disable -r --xim
gdm         2183       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gsd-printer
gdm         2185    2179  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-dconf
gdm         2192       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
gdm         2199    2179  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-engine-simple
gdm         2202       1  0 01:11 tty1     00:00:00 /usr/libexec/ibus-portal
colord      2212       1  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/colord
gdm         2268    1527  0 01:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-metadata
root        6057       1  0 01:18 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
root        6143       1  0 01:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/virtlogd
root        6562       2  0 01:34 ?        00:00:01 [kworker/2:3-events]
root        7924       2  0 06:06 ?        00:00:00 [loop6]
root        7981       1  0 06:06 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root        8320       2  0 08:34 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0-rcu_gp]
root        8891       2  0 09:30 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0-events]
root        8919    1458  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 sshd: user [priv]
user         8938       1  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
user         8939    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
root        8951       2  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2-events]
user         8954    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
user         8956    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs
user         8958    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
user         8975    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
user         8983    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
user         8995    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
user         9007    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
user         9011    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
user         9015    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/goa-daemon
user         9022    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/goa-identity-service
user         9029    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
user         9035    8938  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
user         9185    8919  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 sshd: user@pts/0
user         9186    9185  0 10:02 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root        9258       2  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:3-events]
root        9259       2  0 10:13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:4-cgroup_destroy]
root        9294       2  0 10:31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root        9330       2  0 11:31 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0-events]
root        9334       2  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:2-events_freezable_power_]
root        9348       2  0 11:53 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:0-events_power_efficient]
root        9352       2  0 12:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:3-events_unbound]
root        9400       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0-events]
root        9403       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1-rcu_gp]
root        9413       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1-cgroup_destroy]
root        9414       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:2-events]
root        9415       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:5-events]
root        9418       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1]
root        9419       2  0 12:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:6]
root        9459       2  0 12:13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:1-events_unbound]
user         9463    9186  0 12:14 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
user@server-1:~$
```

attaching XML dump of this VM:

```
user@server-1:~$ virsh dumpxml docker-1
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>docker-1</name>
  <uuid>dfb49ea5-f6e7-45d1-9422-e3ce97cf6320</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>10485760</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>10485760</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-bionic'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='network'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='none'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>qemu64</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='volume' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source pool='default' volume='docker-1-volume-resized.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdc' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdx' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/app/prod/kvm/storage/common-init-docker-1.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdd' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='piix3-uhci'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:01:00:00:00:01'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='virtio' port='1'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='pty'>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='vga' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
</domain>

user@server-1:~$
```

Comment: Your last `virsh list` is not called via `sudo`, just it uses your own user connection url. Try `sudo virsh -c qemu:///system list --all`. And is `virtlockd` running?

Comment: this account has `sudo` group and I've used `virsh` command like this for half a year. So no difference in error if I use `sudo virsh -c qemu:///system start docker-1`. `virtlockd` is not running.

Comment: Do you know if the lock applied on this file? (I meant it's not somewhere in system cache). Is it Linux locking or something specific to QEMU? I would be happy with any workaround or force action too. How about making backup of configuration and using `undefine`?

Comment: I wanted to say that, IIUC, by default when a user runs `virsh` it uses different URI based on his username. You can check with `env VIRSH_DEBUG=0 LIBVIRT_DEBUG=1 sudo -E virsh list 2>&1 | grep qemu:///` vs `env VIRSH_DEBUG=0 LIBVIRT_DEBUG=1 virsh list 2>&1 | grep qemu:///`. See https://libvirt.org/uri.html#URI_qemu Thus I was thinking maybe your VM was running in different session...

Comment: Iv'e got same output for both commands. At the moment nothing is running if I check `ps -ef | grep qemu`. Yesterday, I've searched whole Google and seems nobody has a clear solution. People somehow solve/work around this and don't report to community. I guess they somehow add this parameter `--force-share`, but I'm not sure how to start VM without using `virsh start`.

Comment: Do you use a shared storage? IMO you should run `virtlockd` anyway. `lslocks` lists local system locks.

Comment: I have started `virtlockd` with `sudo service virtlockd start` successfully. Attached output for 1) `lslocks` 2) `ps -ef` 3) `virsh dumpxml docker-1`. Originally, I have attached disk using this command `virsh attach-disk docker-1 --target vdx --source /apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2 --persistent --driver qemu --subdriver qcow2 --targetbus virtio`. It's a folder for data, not OS. Of course, I'm not able to detach it when VM is not running. Maybe an option would be to remove this stale disk from XML?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to clarify - it's not shared disk. Just as I mentioned, it's a secondary data disk attached to standalone VM to gain more space for app.

Comment: BTW, some info about locking in libvirt https://programmersought.com/article/11863543196/

Comment: Thanks. I've checked documentation. Still can't see anything that makes sense. Based on system this file is not locked. So I've renamed this file by adding `-MOVED`, updated XML with `virsh edit docker-1` to point to new location. Now I'm getting `Is another process using the image [/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd-MOVED.qcow2]?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121183/discussion-between-jiri-b-and-laimison).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it was momentary lock conflict or we shouldn't understand this error directly in some circumstances.

So issue was not visible in `lslocks` output.

Solution was to remove 2 disk duplicates via `virsh edit docker-1`:

```
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdc' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>

    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vdx' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

It can't call same file more than once!

Hope that helps someone

---

I think, I've left this quite long ago when experimented with `virsh attach-disk docker-1 --target vdx --source /apphd/prod/kvm/storage/docker-1-volume-hd.qcow2 --persistent --driver qemu --subdriver qcow2 --targetbus virtio` to attach the storage